# program to take screenshots from usb connected android smartphone continiously

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot

I need to take screenshots from my application running on my android device. Its connected via USB to my computer and thus it is simple to take a single screenshot of the device by refreshing and saving the captured image via the DDMS tool in eclipse. fine. 
But I need to take screenshots continously e.g. every second during several minutes. I can't take these screenshots manually, since I have to manage the application while I want to take the screenshots. Is there a possibility e.g. any computer programe to capture and save the screenshots from my computer continously? The DDMS tool doesn't seem to support such a request.

Recording a video of the device would also satisfy me.

Please without rooting my device!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I need to take screenshots continously e.g. every second during several minutes

You are unlikely to achieve every-second frame rates.

> Is there a possibility e.g. any computer programe to capture and save the screenshots from my computer continously? The DDMS tool doesn't seem to support such a request.

Use [Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/).

> Recording a video of the device would also satisfy me.

Buy a device with HDMI-out support and use an HDMI recorder.

Comment: after unchecking and rechecking the usb debugging mode on my device, it worked and did what I needed, thx!